# How to delete some axis in pgfplots, and how to add labels inside figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to delete the axis in the box of this program. I want to keep the x and y axis, and delete the ones that are in front of them. I tried with xtick=\empty and without, it does not seem to have an effect.

Also, is it possible to add a reference to the graph (example: blue circle equals to X, red square equals to Y, brown circle equals to Z), using the exact color and shape provided by the plot?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{poiss}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{(#1^x)*exp(-#1)/(x!)}%
}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
  samples at = {0,...,10},
  axis x line*=bottom,
  axis y line*=left,
%  xtick=\empty, 
%  ytick=\empty,
  enlargelimits=upper}]
  \addplot +[ycomb] {poiss(1)};
  \addplot +[ycomb] {poiss(2)};
  \addplot +[ycomb] {poiss(4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why have you put all those options in `every axis plot post/.append style`? I'm not entirely sure what you're after though, but try the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}  
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{poiss}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{(#1^x)*exp(-#1)/(x!)}%
}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  samples at = {0,...,10},
  axis x line*=bottom,
  axis y line*=left,
  enlarge x limits=true,enlarge y limits=false]
  \addplot +[ycomb] {poiss(1)};
  \addplot +[ycomb] {poiss(2)};
  \addplot +[ycomb] {poiss(4)};

\addlegendentry{X}
\addlegendentry{Y}
\addlegendentry{Z}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's almost what I want. However, I want to keep the numbers in the X and Y axis! That's why I was blocked, I feel I 'm not putting the right options! Do you have a trick for this?!

Comment: @Jeremy Yes, don't use `xtick=\empty`.